# How to search a string in all HTTP request/response that firebug captures?

Tags: firebug

Say I've used Firebug to record many HTTP requests and responses, how can I search a string in all of them? In this way, I can easily find what a string such as tag name got changed in the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're inside the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) just check the option *Response Bodies* to search within the bodies of the HTTP requests.

[image]